# proc_open() path problem

Tags: php

i'm using linux and php 5.2.12

i have problem with executing proc_open

if i use

```
proc_open('php script.php', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

it will show me error

```
sh: /php: No such file or directory
```

if i use

```
proc_open('/usr/bin/php script.php', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

or

```
proc_open('php script.php', $descriptorspec, $pipes, '/usr/bin/');
```

it still show me same error.

i have no idea why it always append slash in front of command.

any help please?

thanks!

Comment: What is the ouput of `which php` from the commandline?

Comment: I get the feeling this is safe-mode related. Is it enabled?

Comment: which php : /usr/bin/php

Comment: you're right zneak! i have to turn off safe-mode. Problem solved! thanks all

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to turn off safe-mode completely, just set this in your php.ini file

```
safe_mode_exec_dir = "/usr/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
$php = trim(shell_exec('type -P php'));

if (empty($php) !== true)
{
    proc_open($php . ' /path/to/your/script.php', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
}

else
{
    die('Install php-cli!');
}
```